# Parsing an Excel file in C#, the cells seem to get cut off at 255 characters... how do I stop that?

Tags: c#, linq, excel, excel-2007, xlsx

I am parsing through an uploaded excel files (xlsx) in asp.net with c#. I am using the following code (simplified):

```
string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";");
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connString);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
adapter.Dispose();
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
var rows = from p in dt.AsEnumerable() select new { desc = p[2] };
```

This works perfectly, *but* if there is anything longer than 255 characters in the cell, it will get cut off.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

EDIT: When viewing the excel sheet, it shows much more than 255 characters, so I don't believe the sheet itself is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from a quick Googling of the subject, it appears that that's a limit of Excel.

**EDIT**: [Possible workaround (unfortunately in VB)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213841)

Comment: How can it be limited when I am looking at the sheet and it shows more than 255 characters?

Comment: From the "Cause" section of the article I linked: "For example, if you pass a text string that is longer than 255 characters to a text box on a worksheet or a dialog sheet, Excel truncates the text even though a text box can hold up to 10,240 characters. "

Answer (score 21):

### The Solution!

I've been battling this today as well. I finally got it to work by modifying some registry keys before parsing the Excel spreadsheet.

You must update this registry key before parsing the Excel spreadsheet:

```
// Excel 2010
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\
or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\

// Excel 2007
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\

// Excel 2003
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\
```

Change `TypeGuessRows` to `0` and `ImportMixedTypes` to `Text` under this key. You'll also need to update your connection string to include `IMEX=1` in the extended properties:

```
string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";");
```

---

### References

http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/aanttila/Blog/archive/2008/03/28/excel-and-csv-reference.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx

> ...characters may be truncated. **To import
>   data from a memo column without
>   truncation, you must make sure that
>   the memo column in at least one of the
>   sampled rows contains a value longer
>   than 255 characters, or you must
>   increase the number of rows sampled by
>   the driver to include such a row.** You
>   can increase the number of rows
>   sampled by increasing the value of
>   TypeGuessRows under the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
>   registry key....

Comment: Thank you! Even Microsoft's own KB article points to the same key but in the wrong location! Once I followed your instructions, everything worked!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it fixed it for me. Your answer made it possible to fix this in just 30 minutes instead of a whole day! :)

Comment: I tried with the same solution. But it is not working for me. Can you please suggest

Answer (score 8):

I have came across this, and the solution that worked for me was to move the cells with long text to the top of the spreadsheet.

I found this comment in a forum describing the issue

> This is an issue with the Jet OLEDB provider. It looks at the first **8 rows**
>   of the
>   spreadsheet to determine the data type in each column. If the column does
>   not contain
>   a field value over 256 characters in the first **8 rows**, then it assumes the
>   data type
>   is text, which has a character limit of 256. The following KB article has
>   more
>   information on this issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517

Hope this help someone else!

Comment: It works for me. I just moved row to the top of the worksheet and a cell was not cutted off after 256 characters anymore. For static data source it is simplest workaround.

Comment: This worked for me!

Quick tip if the order of the data doesn't matter. Add a column called Length, add the formula `=LEN(YOUR LONG TEXT CELL)` and then sort descending by that column. Puts all of the longest text at the top quickly!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the columns datatype to text within the spreadsheet? I believe doing this will allow the cells to contain much more than 255 characters.

[Edit]
For what it's worth [this dialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2005/09/26/474258.aspx) with the MS-Excel team is an interesting read. In the comments section at the bottom they get into some discussions about that 255 cutoff. They say Excel 12 can support 32k characters per cell.

If that is true there must be a way to get at this data. Here is two things to consider.

1. In the past I have used the "IMEX=1" option in my connection string to deal with columns containing mixed data showing up as empty. It's a longshot, but you might give that a try.
2. Could you export the file to a tab delimited flat file? IMHO this is the most reliable way of dealing with Excel data, since Excel does have so many gotchas.

Comment: When you look at the Excel file in Excel is the data cut off, or does it all show?

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can read and write (and more) xls and xlsx workbooks and supports the same limitations as Excel for text - in other words it will just work. There is a free evaluation if you want to give it a try.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the last post, I also use SpreadsheetGear and find that it also suffers from the 255 characters per cell limitation when reading from the older XLS (not XLSX) format.