# VBA Excel SQL Query limits fields to 255 characters

Tags: sql, excel, vba

When doing a simple select * query to an excel workbook, it cuts off text after  255 characters. Are recordset fields limited to 255 characters? if not, how can I get the full field text from the recordset?

[image: img1]
The test line should have over 1400 characters
All other line items are less than 255 characters, and are correct.

```vb
Sub ExportCallLogs()

Dim conn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim dbpath As String

' Create the connection string.
dbpath = "mypathhere.xlsx"

' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' Open the connection and execute.
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbpath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]")

' Check we have data.
If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

'print headers and recordset
Workbooks.Add
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

Columns.AutoFit
Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 55

' Clean up
rs.Close
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you upload sample workbook to some cloud storage?

Comment: I found that the fields are limited to 255 characters, and updated my question. Let me know if you still need an example WB.

Comment: If you think there's a limit, then why text is cut off with variable length? Please, upload workbook.

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload a workbook. Just joined and it looks like others have said it's against the rules, and I don't see an option.

Comment: You can upload to Google Drive or OneDrive or DropBox - and attach a link.

Comment: See this for an explanation and workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865183/data-truncated-after-255-bytes-while-using-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider

Comment: That let me to the answer. Thank you! Steven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the very weird problem, and solution. This ended up working for exporting data through a query and inserting data.

> This is an issue with the Jet OLEDB provider. It looks at the first 8
>   rows of the spreadsheet to determine the data type in each column. If
>   the column does not contain a field value over 256 characters in the
>   first 8 rows, then it assumes the data type is text, which has a
>   character limit of 256. The following KB article has more information
>   on this issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517

Comment: I don't see the URL that you shared as an actual working link, but everything you stated sounds totally correct.

Comment: I added empty spaces so that it doesn't look weird to end user :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can often work around this by changing the format of the Excel column from Text to General.

Comment: Its currently set to General

Comment: This is not working