MS Excel data is being truncated when inserting into MS SQL Server?
Can someone assist me?
Problem statement: I am trying to upload data into SQL Server. But for some reason, the string data is being truncated.
Input Data
Sourcing, Talent Acquisition, Executive Search, Market Research, Negotiation, Employer Branding, 猎头 (招聘), 经营策略, HR Consulting, Team Management, 市场情况调查, Employee Engagement, Recruitment Advertising, Account Management, Business Development, Talent Management, 管理人员, Technical Recruiting, CRM, Recruiting, Interviews, Management, Screening, Business Strategy, Performance Management, Leadership, Screening Resumes, Contract Recruitment, Management Consulting, Human Resources, New Business Development, Strategy

Uploaded data in SQL Server:
Sourcing, Talent Acquisition, Executive Search, Market Research, Negotiation, Employer Branding, 猎头 (招聘), 经营策略, HR Consulting, Team Management, 市场情况调查, Employee Engagement, Recruitment Advertising, Account Management, Business Development, Talent Manageme

This is my code:
Dim con_Excl            As New ADODB.Connection             ' Create Excel Connection
Dim rst_Excl            As New ADODB.Recordset              ' Create Recordset of Excel



' Set Connection String
strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & strLeads_Source_File_Path & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
                
                
' Open Connection
con_Excl.Open strConnString

' Set Query
strQryExcelSrc = "SELECT * FROM [Leads$]"

' Set Recordset
rst_Excl.Open strQryExcelSrc, con_Excl

' Create Connection
Set con_LeadsSrc = RecturnMSSQLCon

' Set Recordset
rst_LeadsSrc.Open "tbl_Leads_Source_Temp", con_LeadsSrc, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic


' Print the Value
While rst_Excl.EOF = False
    rst_LeadsSrc.AddNew
    rst_LeadsSrc.Fields("Top_Skills") = rst_Excl.Fields("Top_Skills")
    rst_LeadsSrc.Fields("Email") = rst_Excl.Fields("Email")
    rst_LeadsSrc.Update
    rst_Excl.MoveNext
Wend

I am trying to upload data into SQL Server. But to some reason data is truncated.

How long is your string - and how many characters does the column in the database table hold as a maximum (what is the column's datatype) ?

Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901116/7446760

what does: exec sp_help tbl_Leads_Source_Temp outputs when it comes to column length

Microsoft stopped supporting MDAC 12 and removed the download links for it some years ago. Have you considered upgrading?

You might have an issue because the driver needs to guess the data type of your Excel data. It guesses according to the first entries in a column. If the first rows have strings that are shorter than 256 chars, it assumes a short string and cut the data.
